# Having trouble with ActionEvent and getText() in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionevent

and thanks for taking a look at my question.

I am working on a program that accepts user input for height and width and, depending on which option is chosen from a drop down menu, either calculates the area of a rectangle or the circumference of a circle.

I have everything working, so far, but am having trouble with the ActionEvents. What I need guidance on is how to change the calculation formulas depending on which option is chosen from the drop down menu.

I'm also having trouble setting up the computebtn to compute the area or circumference depending on which formula has been selected, and getting the input from the JTextFields to be used in the formulas. If I try to use getText() I get this error:

```
    error: incompatible types: string cannot be converted to int
```

TL;DR: Need help implementing two ActionEvents. One to change labels and formulas and one to handle the computebtn in order to obtain an answer. Also need help getting the input from the user into the formulas.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class areaOrCircumference extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    int height;
    int width;
    int area;
    int circumference;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    JButton computebtn = new JButton("Compute");
    JLabel widthlbl = new JLabel("Enter Width:");
        JTextField widthfld = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel heightlbl = new JLabel("Enter Height:");
        JTextField heightfld = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel outputlbl = new JLabel();

    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel computePanel = new JPanel();

    public areaOrCircumference()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            labelPanel.add(label);
        add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
            inputPanel.add(widthlbl);
            inputPanel.add(widthfld);
            inputPanel.add(heightlbl);
            inputPanel.add(heightfld);
            inputPanel.add(outputlbl);
        add(computePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            computePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            computePanel.add(computebtn);
            computebtn.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar()
    {
        JMenuBar mnuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(mnuBar);

        JMenu mnuType = new JMenu("Type", true);
        mnuBar.add(mnuType);

        JMenuItem mnuArea = new JMenuItem("Area");
            mnuType.add(mnuArea);
            mnuArea.setActionCommand("Area");
            mnuArea.addActionListener(this);

        JMenuItem mnuCirc = new JMenuItem("Circumference");
            mnuType.add(mnuCirc);
            mnuCirc.setActionCommand("Circumference");
            mnuCirc.addActionListener(this);

        return mnuBar;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String arg = e.getActionCommand();

        if(arg == "Area")
        {
            label.setText("Area of a rectangle");
            area = width*height;
        }

        if(arg =="Circumference")
        {
            label.setText("Circumference of a Circle");
            circumference = 2*width + 2*height;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        areaOrCircumference f = new areaOrCircumference();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setJMenuBar(f.createMenuBar());
        f.setTitle("Area/Circumference Calculator");
        f.setBounds(300,300,475,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This, `if(arg == "Area")` worries me. Don't compare Strings with `==`. Use `equals(...)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that is simply the action command from the drop down menu used to determine which choice has been made

Comment: It doesn't matter what it is for -- it's wrong and can lead to non-functioning program logic.

Comment: Please check out edits to answer. Please ask if any questions about it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There is a drop down menu "Type" that has two options: "Area" or "Circumference". The user first chooses one of these options which will determine what calculation is to be done with the entered numbers. The computebtn then calculates the user entered data once the type of calculation has been chosen and the data has been entered. My question would be: where do I put the formulas so that the formula corresponds with the choice made from the menu, and how do I get the computebtn to then calculate that formula and display to my outputlbl?

Comment: @AndrewThompson as of right now, I have the formulas under each if statement. What I'm having trouble with is how do I get the computebtn to work on these formulas? Do I need another ActionEvent or can the one I already have handle both the choice from the menu and the button press to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't compare Strings with `==` since this compares for reference equality, i.e., if one String refers to the same String object as another variable, something you don't care about. You want to test if each String holds the same chars in the same order, and for that test for String equality with the `equals(...)` method. Or use the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` if you don't care about case. So change `if(arg == "Area")` to `if(arg.equals("Area"))`
2. Get your JTextField text with `getText()`, but then parse the String into an int with `Integer.parseInt(...)` before trying to use it as an int.

i.e.,

```
int width = Integer.parseInt(widthfld.getText());
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes more sense now. And I feel dumb because I was trying to user the .parseInt() but I was forgetting the Integer before the "."

Comment: Now, how would I handle the ActionEvent for the computebtn?

Comment: @ebonymessiah: I don't understand your question above. How is computebtn different? What *exactly* has you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly to put the formulas or how to get the computebtn to compute the chosen formula. In other words, can the ActionEvent I already have handle both choosing the formula and the button click to calculate? I'm super new to java

Comment: @ebonymessiah: I'm still confused as to just what you want that button to do? What calculation? How does the user tell the GUI which calculation to do when that button has been pushed?

Comment: There is a drop down menu "Type" that has two options: "Area" or "Circumference". The user first chooses one of these options which will determine what calculation is to be done with the entered numbers. The computebtn simply calculates the user entered data once the type of calculation has been chosen and the data has been entered. Hope that clarifies things a little bit

Comment: @ebonymessiah: then you need to store the selection somewhere and use that information in the button's ActionListener. Myself, I'd use something that remains visible on the GUI so the user can see what they've selected and easily change, and would not use menus. For example I'd use a pair of JRadioButtons.

Comment: There is a label at the top of the GUI that shows either "Area of a Rectangle" or "Circumference of a Circle" depending on which option is chosen. The point of the exercise is to use the drop down menu to handle the choice. I'm just stuck on how to handle switching the formula and coding the compute btn to calculate

Comment: @ebonymessiah: then however you're showing the user -- use that information to decide what formula to use. I am confident that you can figure this out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Im sure that, if I bang my head against this a few more times, I can get it to work properly